# Minimize fails to find a minimum

Tags: mathematical-optimization, symbolic

I am trying to find, analytically, the $\theta,\phi$ that minimize the function U($\theta,\phi$)

```
Clear[h, d]
m = {Sin[θ] Cos[ϕ], Sin[θ] Sin[ϕ], Cos[θ]};
n = {Sin[θn] Cos[ϕn], Sin[θn] Sin[ϕn],Cos[θn]};
H = h {0, 0, 1};
U = -H.m - d (n.m)^2
```

where `h` and `d` are positive. `θn` and `ϕn` are fixed variables.

How can I find the value of $\theta,\phi$ that minimizes U($\theta,\phi$)?

I tried to use

```
Minimize[{U, h > 0, d > 0}, {θ, ϕ}]
```

It is not successful, Mathematica just returns the input as the output.

What is the proper way of doing this problem?

---

#### Update

I solved it manually. $dU/d\phi=0$ leads to $\phi=\phi_n$ or $\pi+\phi_n/\pi$, and, therefore, $dU/d\theta=0$ gives the equation for $\theta$ as

$\qquad h\sin\theta+d\sin[2(\theta\pm\theta_n)]=0$

Mathmematica is able to give a long analytical solution. I have to use a numerical result for given values of d,h,$\theta_n$, $\phi_n$.

Comment: Is: `θn` or: `θ*n` ?

Comment: θn is $\theta_n$,  θn and ϕn are fixed variables

Comment: The minimum should be a root of $\nabla U$, and you can see that there is no closed-form solution in general.

Comment: you mean there is no analytical solution?

Comment: How can you get a numerical result if some parameters are symbolic?

Comment: give values for d,h,$\theta_n$, $\phi_n$

Answer (score 1):

Evidently it's having trouble with the transcendental equation.  Plug in values and it can do it numerically.

```
d = .5
h = .5
θn = 45 °
ϕn = 30 °

Minimize[U, {θ, ϕ}]
(*{-0.899519, {θ -> 0.523599, ϕ -> 0.523599}}*)
```

You need to test your own values, since I don't know what reasonable input value are.

Comment: Ideally, I hope to get an analytical solution. If there is no analytical one, I will have to use the numerical one.

Comment: I can't see why this should have been down-voted

Comment: If you use exact values for `d` and `h` (i.e., `1/2`) the minimum is `{1/8 (-2 - 3 Sqrt[3]), {\[Theta] -> \[Pi]/6, \[Phi] -> \[Pi]/6}}` and `{1/8 (-2 - 3 Sqrt[3]), {\[Theta] -> (11 \[Pi])/6, \[Phi] -> (7 \[Pi])/
   6}}`